# How can I programmatically sign (via corp provided certificate) an Excel workbook/xls?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a 'release' process (written in C#) that checks a file out of SharePoint, loads it into Excel (via Interop), executes a couple of macros, saves the changed file, then checks in back in.

I'd like to add a final step that after save but before check-in digitally signs the file with a certificate.  I've looked into XML encryption, but not all the files to be signed are XML docs (many are older Excel 97 XLS files).

Currently I do all my processing via the seperate C# application.  I'd prefer to keep the functionality there but if doing it in SharePoint is a better option I'm interested in hearing details.

Thoughts from the hive-mind? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the advice from [this msdn forum post?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b888b80-1259-4c93-92fe-70784ed9cd0a/excel-document-digital-signature-with-c)

> Get a code signing certificate from a authorized certification
>   authority. Install it to the certificate store. After you generate
>   each Excel file, use System.Diagnostics.Process to execute one of the
>   available commercial signing tools for office documents.
>
> Open Xml Signer for example uses the
>   System.IO.PackageDigitalSignatureManager.Sign()-method to sign
>   documents. Have a look at the documentation and reflect over the
>   application to do the signing programmatically in your application.
>
> System.IO.Packaging-Namespace

Comment: I took a look at the article, but essentially is suggests shelling out to a command line tool.  I'd like to find something more .NET based.